# How to get the URL of an instance created from a class- SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift, url, alamofire

I am trying to upload a newly created PDFDocument instance to a server.  I would like to use Alamofire and part of the parameters required for the upload is a file URL.  My question is how do I get the URL of this newly created instance?

```
 // Create new PDFDocument
 let newDoc = PDFDocument.init()
```

Alamofire uploading function:

```
 Alamofire.upload(fileURL, to: "myLinkGoesHere").responseJSON { response in
debugPrint(response)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Newly create an instance of the `PDFDocument` doesn't have any URL or File Path until you write the data into. There is two way you can upload the pdf document on the server.

**1. Using Data:**

You can still upload the data to the server using data. You need to use a different method of Almofire API to upload it to the server.

```
// Create new PDFDocument
let newDoc = PDFDocument()
//Get the data from the newly created document
if let data = newDoc.dataRepresentation() {
   //Upload the data using Almofire. 
   Alamofire.upload(data, to: "myLinkGoesHere").responseJSON { response in

   }
}
```

**2. Write the pdf into file path and upload using URL.**

```
    //Create a new document 
    let newDoc = PDFDocument()
    /*Perform certain task and add some content into document

    end of the adding content into document*/
    //Now save the document into file path
    let path = "~/path/to/doc/to/be/saved.pdf"
    newDoc.write(toFile: path)
    //Create file path url 
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    //start upload processing using url
    Alamofire.upload(url, to: "myLinkGoesHere").responseJSON { response in }
```

Comment: Can I capture this file upload using PHP $_FILE?

Comment: you should be, if not then you can try to write the file first into a local directory and then upload it.